# Settings Intent is not working in SAMSUMG M51

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, settings, android-pendingintent

I am using below code :

```
 var intent=Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS)
        startActivityForResult(
            intent,
            REQUEST_SETTINGS
        )
```

But it's not opening the Settings screen. I am testing it in SAMSUNG M51.

What might be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: "I have to use startActivity for result" -- `ACTION_SETTINGS` [does not return a result](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/Settings#action_settings)

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, have you tried this ? :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

> Also, this is useful as well :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(
    "com.android.settings",
    "com.android.settings.Settings$DeviceInfoSettingsActivity"
);
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: I have to use startActivity for result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to open settings and now its updated way , will work `startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS))`

Comment: I have tried on SAMSUNG J7 Prime its worked.

Comment: I have to use startActivity for result.

Comment: Okay , would you try this startActivityForResult(Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS),0)

Comment: Yes I have tried.

Comment: Then what happened ? Still its not worked for SAMSUNG M51 ?